# Dockerized Nginx + Certbot + tls-sni challenge not working on renewal

Tags: nginx, docker, lets-encrypt, sni

I have an existing service running using docker containers:

- nginx (`nginx:1.13.5`)
- node-api (node container)
- node-website (node container)

I wanted to add SSL certificates for both api and website. So I've used `certbot/certbot` docker container to do so, without any problem.

I've generate the certificates using `dns` challenge, running the following command (from my local machine):

```
docker run --rm -it \
  --name certbot \
  -v $(pwd)/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt \
  certbot/certbot \
    certonly --manual -d api.mydomain.com --preferred-challenges dns --renew-by-default --email xxx@xxxx --agree-tos --manual-public-ip-logging-ok
```

I was asked to enter TXT dns record for `_acme-challenge.api.mydomain.com` which I did, and got the certificates generated without any issues.

I then updated my Nginx configuration (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf/api.conf`):

```
upstream api {
  server node-api:5000 max_fails=3;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default       "upgrade";
  ""            "";
}

# Force HTTPS
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.domain.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name       api.domain.com;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_certificate   /etc/nginx/certificates/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/api.domain.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/api.domain.com/chain.pem;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/api-domain.access.log main;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/api-domain.error.log error;

  location / {
    proxy_pass         http://api;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

And all good, restarted my server and now running perfectly with letsencrypt certificates! Awesome!

---

**The problem**

Now come the test of renewing the certificates... And here comes the troubles. First I just tried to run the `renew --dry-run` command without much of a success.

> Attempting to renew cert (api.mydomain.com) from
>   /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/api.mydomain.com.conf produced an unexpected
>   error: The manual plugin is not working; there may be problems with
>   your existing configuration. The error was: PluginError('An
>   authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when
>   using the manual plugin non-interactively.',). Skipping.

So I've tried using the standalone option:

```
docker run --rm -it \
  --name certbot \
  -v $(pwd)/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt \
  certbot/certbot \
    renew --dry-run --standalone --preferred-challenges dns
```

and got this error:

> Attempting to renew cert (api.mydomain.com) from
>   /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/api.mydomain.com.conf produced an unexpected
>   error: None of the preferred challenges are supported by the selected
>   plugin. Skipping.

So I'm deducting that I cannot use `dns` challenges for the renewal of the certificate, fair enough.

Let's try with `tls-sni` that Nginx is supporting (I verified, it is enabled)

```
docker run --rm -it \
  --name certbot \
  -v $(pwd)/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt \
  certbot/certbot \
    renew --dry-run --standalone --preferred-challenges tls-sni
```

And now I have this error:

> Attempting to renew cert (api.mydomain.com) from
>   /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/api.mydomain.com.conf produced an unexpected
>   error: Failed authorization procedure. api.mydomain.com (tls-sni-01):
>   urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient
>   authorization :: Incorrect validation certificate for tls-sni-01
>   challenge. Requested
>   e0fd03ddade6d902d5947028985253ba.63b177f317335bf9297f0bb963135fee.acme.invalid
>   from 13.210.106.2:443. Received 2 certificate(s), first certificate
>   had names "api.mydomain.com". Skipping.

I'm wondering if I need to enable something specific on Nginx side such as `OCSP`, `ssl_stapling` or `ssl_dhparam`

I've also noticed that if I'm trying to re-run the certonly on a different server than I got the certificates from, the `dns` challenge value is not the same.

---

**So I have 2 questions:**

- Can I easily fix the `tls-sni` verification challenge tuning the nginx configuration?
- If I re-run `certonly` with `dns` challenge on the actual server (where nginx container is running), updating the TXT record with the new ones generated. Can I renew certificates later on, using `certonly` command? Will the TXT record values change over time?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much activity on ServerFault, so here is the answer:

https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5252#issuecomment-346500852

Answer (score 1):

Thanks maxwell2022! Here's what my final solution looks like, based on your answer. Tested on CentOS 7. I manually created the directory /etc/letsencrypt/acme-challenge.

### NGINX Server Block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MY_DOMAIN;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /etc/letsencrypt/acme-challenge;
    }
}
```

### Create the Cert

```
docker run -it --rm --name certbot -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt -v /var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt certbot/certbot certonly --webroot -w /etc/letsencrypt/acme-challenge/ --domain MY_DOMAIN --agree-tos --email MY_EMAIL
```

### Renew the Cert

```
docker run -it --rm --name certbot -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt -v /var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt certbot/certbot renew --webroot -w /etc/letsencrypt/acme-challenge/
docker kill --signal=HUP proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't your problem when the issue first occurred, but it'd cause problems now so I'll mention it:

[The TLS-SNI challenges are being phased out](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/important-what-you-need-to-know-about-tls-sni-validation-issues/50811), as they are insecure under many common hosting platforms. If you are currently relying on having certificates issued this way, you will need to transition to HTTP- or DNS-based challenges.